# Proof of injectivity given a commutative diagram.

Tags: linear-algebra

I was going through the textbook *Linear Algebra*, By Klaus Janich, and encountered this problem(problem 1.3):

*Let*:

\begin{align*} X \quad\xrightarrow{f}\quad Y\,\,\,\\
\alpha\uparrow\cong\qquad\beta\uparrow\cong
\\
A \quad\xrightarrow{g}\quad B \,\,\,
\end{align*}

*be a commutative diagram of maps with $\alpha$, $\beta$ bijective. Show that g is injective
if and only if f is injective.*

I tried coming up with a proof but I'm still insecure about my proof-writing skills so I don't know if this is completely correct. It is as follows:

Because $\alpha$, $\beta$ are bijective, and inverse is well defined for both, thus:

$$f \circ \alpha = \beta \circ g \iff \beta^{-1} \circ f \circ \alpha = g $$

Which is injective if f is injective. And the other way around to prove "*g injective $\rightarrow$ f injective*". Is this correct? Could you also recommend another method? I would like to get used to proofs so I would love the exposure to something different from my way of thinking.

[(screenshot of problem.)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0782J.png)

Comment: This is a perfectly good proof! (assuming you already know that the composition of injective functions is injective) Another method is to start by embracing the logical structure of the statement to be proved. For example, here one thing to prove is "if $f$ is injective then $g$ is injective". So the proof "must" go: "Assume $f$ is injective. Suppose that $s,t\in A$ satisfy $g(s)=g(t)$. [middle of proof] Then $s=t$. This proves that $g$ is injective." Somewhere in "middle of proof", the assumptions on $f,\alpha,\beta$ will be used (as it turns out, only $f,\alpha$ in this case).

Comment: Thanks! It's really a matter of getting used to it I guess! Also, do you know if I can look at the history of a post? There was an answer that I was trying to follow and work out on paper, but I think they deleted it!

Comment: Users with enough points can see deleted posts (I can see the one you mean), but I'm not sure what you can do as a new user....